# Position of conjunctions: Beginning of a sentence Vs Near beginning of a sentence

Tags: conjunctions

When should one use conjunctions, such as "therefore" and "nevertheless," at each of the following positions:

- Beginning of a sentence
- Near beginning of a sentence.

For example:

- She is to give light.  Therefore, she must endure burning.
- She is to give light.  She must, therefore, endure burning.

Is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: Consider as another example: Therefore, he decided to become a sailor, and, in 1848, tramping across the country to Cleveland, Ohio, he sought employment from the captain of a lake schooner. **VS** He decided, therefore, to become a sailor, and, in 1848, tramping across the country to Cleveland, Ohio, he sought employment from the captain of a lake schooner.

Comment: I know both usages are correct. My question is whether any one of them is preferred over the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a cleaner approach, don't split:
To give light, he must endure burning
To give light, she must endure burning

Comment: or: she gives light, so she must burn

Comment: or she will give light, so she must burn

Comment: That was just an example. Consider as another example: He decided, therefore, to become a sailor, and, in 1848, tramping across the country to Cleveland, Ohio, he sought employment from the captain of a lake schooner. VS Therefore, he decided to become a sailor, and, in 1848, tramping across the country to Cleveland, Ohio, he sought employment from the captain of a lake schooner.

Comment: I would delete therefore in first instance (redundant).  VS also redundant.

Comment: In 1848, tramping across the country to Cleveland Ohio, he sought employment from the captain of a lake schooner.  VS decided to become a sailor, and, in 1848, after slogging (or alternative due to repetition of tramping) across the country to Cleveland Ohio, he begged employment from the Captian of a lake schooner

Answer (score 0):

**Therefore** is a conjunction and it can be used instead of **so** in formal English. It can come at the beginning of the clause or after the first word or phrase; or before the main verb.

eg - This is a popular item; you should, therefore, expect the price to be rather high .

When two contrasting statements are mentioned, **nevertheless** would be used.

eg -

They hadn't trained hard, but nevertheless they won

or

they won,nevertheless.

Comment: I know both usages are correct. My question is whether any one of them is preferred over the other one.

Comment: As long as the meaning is conveyed in the intended way, it shouldn't be an issue as to where you place it.

Comment: I  know it is not an issue. I just wonder whether there are situations when one may be preferred over the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but in this case it does not enhance the narrative, therefore it's use should be rethought in terms of the whole

Comment: Too many conjunctions and adverbs make for muddy prose. My view :-), fully open for alternative views!

Comment: Eish, I am not sure of the purpose of this website, so I may be making some controversial statements.  i love the english language, I am enamored with others who share my passion, but, is this a grammar hound venue or a site of language lovers who love debate?

Comment: meant a site 'for', damn autocorrect1